# In PHP, how do I ask a mySQL database to retrieve multiple most recent records that match a certain value?

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have a table that has the following fields:

```
candy_name
candy_type
candy_amount
candy_vendor
```

One candy_type can have multiple candy_names, like "gummis" might have "orange," "watermelon," "sour watermelon," and so on.

What I am doing is searching this table by vendor, and then I want to see the most recent entry for each unique candy_type (ignoring candy_name).  That is, the most recently added row for each unique candy_type.

So I found out how to do the part about finding all the unique candy_types in that table:

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT candy_type FROM candy_table 
               WHERE candy_vendor LIKE '%$user_searchbox_input%' 
               ORDER BY candy_vendor ASC";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Now I need to find out how to retrieve the MOST RECENT record for each unique candy_type.

Like for the candy_type of "gummi," if the last record matching that type was "orange," that's the one I want to see---not the others.
And for the candy_type of "chocolate," if the last matching record was "milk," I don't care about the others, but I want to retrieve that most recent record matching that candy_type.

How do I do that?

Comment: How do you define "the most recent"?  Is it the ones added last or the ones updated last?  Or the ones accessed last?  What is your table structure? You don't seem to provide enough information.

Comment: @Aleks, you don't need that much info, Jerry can just make his own changes to the code. Most recent = `having timestamp = max(timestamp)` all the OP needs to do is rename the field to fit his DB schema.

Comment: @Aleks, the ones added last.
It hadn't occurred to me that it might be misleading; I will change my original post. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the most recent, use a `having` clause, combined with a `group by`, because the group by already selects distinct columns, you can drop the `distinct` clause.

```
$user_searchbox_input = mysql_real_escape_string($user_searchbox_input);
$sql = "SELECT candy_type FROM candy_table 
               WHERE candy_vendor LIKE '%$user_searchbox_input%' 
               GROUP BY candy_vendor 
               HAVING timeadded = MAX(timeadded)
               ORDER BY candy_vendor ASC";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

See: http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/having.php

Comment: I do have a candy_date field...Should I use that?  Or is "timeadded" a PHP / MYSQL thing I don't know about?

Comment: @Jerry, good, substitute that the the `timeadded` field, no `timeadded` is just my invention. I may patent it if it catches on though.

Comment: I think this will work; but for the HAVING clause, how do I say "choose the largest value for candy_date"?

Comment: @Jerry, please don't be silly: `HAVING candy_date = MAX(candy_date)`

Comment: And I believe I have found my answer!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, from those four columns there's no way of telling which record is the most recent.

I would suggest adding a date_time column via the ALTER TABLE command.  You can refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html for syntax help if you need it.

This won't help you with your current query, but it will help for any future queries.

Comment: I do have a time_column, but wasn't sure if it was necessary, or if it could just check the most recent row in the database.

Knowing I already have such a column that is already populated with useful data, what now?

Comment: If you have a time column and it holds the date/time of the record insertion, then I would do the following:  "SELECT <columns> FROM candy_table ORDER BY <date_column> DESC LIMIT 1".

Comment: If the PK is integer auto_increment then that's a pretty good vector for creation time, no timestamp field needed.

Answer (score -1):

Sort your data by create_date (ORDER BY) or whatever your create timestamp is and then do SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 1;     # Retrieve first row